# File not streaming as expected in Asp.Net Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to upload file to my onedrive, getting the file as expected seems streaming not process accordingly, could anyone please point me the problem.

**Code snippet:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileOnFolder(IFormFile uploadedFile, string folderName)
{
    try
    {
        if (uploadedFile.Length > 0)
        {
            dynamic response;
            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(uploadedFile.FileName).FileName.Trim('"');

            using var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName));
                response =  await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Items[folderName].Content
                                  .Request()
                                  .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);

            ViewData["FileUploadInfo"] = response;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["message"] = "Sorry Upload failed! Please check your file!";
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
     }

     return RedirectToAction("RecentDirveInfo");
}
```

**Note:** I am following [this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: `UTF8.GetBytes(fileName)` returns the UTF8 representation of the filename, not the file's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileOnFolder(IFormFile uploadedFile, string folderName)
        {
            try
            {

                if (uploadedFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    dynamic response;

                    var fileName = uploadedFile.FileName;
                    using var stream = uploadedFile.OpenReadStream();
                    response = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(folderName +"/" + fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
                        
                    ViewData["FileUploadInfo"] = response;
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["message"] = "Sorry check your file!";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("RecentDirveInfo");
        }
```

I have tested it on my side it works for me perfectly:

Btw, make sure you have granted **Delegated Permissions** below to your Azure AD application before you run this code :

```
Files.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All
```

Comment: How is this different than the original code? Code-only answers are acceptable if the solution is clear, but that's not the case here. What has changed in all this code?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Use code : '_graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(folderName +"/" + fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);' instead of '_graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Items[folderName].Content
                                  .Request()
                                  .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);'

Comment: Thanks for your exact point which I was trying in wrong way! In this line ` response = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(folderName +"/" + fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);`

Comment: *Update the answer* and make it clear what the relevant parts are. One can't understand what you did before reading the other answers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had two problem one is streming and rigth format I have tried this line from the begining ' await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].Content .Request() .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);` but cannot make it work.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, glad to know it is helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the APi, but I do know you are trying to upload the file name as the file. You will likely want to use [`uploadedFile.OpenReadStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and instead pass that into `PutAsync`

> Opens the request stream for reading the uploaded file.

```
using var stream = uploadedFile.OpenReadStream();
response =  await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Items[folderName].Content
                 .Request()
                 .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

Comment: Tryied your solution seems stream working fine but still getting exception on upload `Invalid request`, did you uploaded files successfully?

Comment: There might be other bugs too. You need to take this correction into account anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort on this. I got the answer which I am looking for.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron all good, good luck :)